# Is it allowed to store pictures of living things in Digital format?

Tags: halal-haram, image, digital-files

I know that it is prohibited to draw or sketch pictures of living thing in Islam. But is it allowed to store those pictures in your Laptop/Computer/Mobile or any other digital device? Since the picture is not in intangible format but in the form of bytes, and can only be read by specific digital device. Moreover it is not always in visible form and can only be visible when clicked to open

Answer (score 1):

I am a Muslim by the grace of Almighty one. I think that pictures are not forbidden in Islam to be sketched or taken by devices because first is, I have never read it in Koran, the comprehensive guide. And if it is just stated in hadith then it should be justified under the light of Koran or if it can't be so then we can use philosophy to derive its rightest. What my brain says is, they would not have been forbidden because camera works as same as eye and we store pictures in our devices as in mind. What the difference is? If it is nothing and also we are not forbidden to keep photos saved in our mind then you can think that there must have been no ban on depiction. However depiction is verily used as in Id cards, passports e.t.c.

Comment: There's a hadith which translates as `Angels of Rehmat don't enter on those houses where there is any picture of a living thing or a dog`

Comment: But when we deal with hadiths we have a need of justification always. And when we deal with Koran, we have to rely on it. There are even the impressive instances i can reveal to you that will urge you to say 'yes'. Assume it is stated in Koran that it is all wrong which is stated in Koran then you have to believe it even though you can not think about that.

Comment: But on the other hand if you would see the above statement in hadith than you would at once deny the hadith. won't you? So this is the difference between Hadith and Koran!